# Linear Mixed Model in R - Equation

Tags: r, mixed-model, panel-data, linear, model

I have a linear mixed model with a random effect. The associated `R` code is

```
lmer(log_wmh ~ 1 + viscode * dx_official + (1 | PTID) + AGE + PTGENDER + PTEDUCAT)
```

What would be the most appropriate way to write the equation out for this model? I was a bit confused and would appreciate any clarification. Also, any insight on how to explain the error term in the resulting equation? I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Edit: would it be like this?

```
Y_{it} = \beta_{0} + \beta_1(\viscode_{it}) + \beta_2(\diagnosis_{i}) + \beta_4(\age_{i}) + \beta_4(\gender_{i}) + \beta_5(\education_{i}) + \alpha_{i} + \epsilon_{it}
```

Comment: An adjunct to the @wonderer answer - you could try applying the `equatiomatic` package to the fitted model

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a sample of $n$ units
\begin{align*}
\log(y_{i}) = \alpha + \beta^\top \mathbf{X}_i + \delta_{g(i)}W_{g(i)} + \epsilon_i,\quad \epsilon_i\sim N(0,\sigma_\epsilon^2),\quad \delta_g\sim N(\delta,\sigma_\delta^2)
\end{align*}
where $y_i$ is $\texttt{wmh}_i$, $\mathbf{X}_i=(\texttt{viscode}_i\times\texttt{dx_official}_i,\texttt{age}_i,\texttt{PTGENDER}_i,\texttt{PTEDUCAT}_i)^\top$, and $W_{g(i)}$ is $\texttt{PTID}_i$. Finally, $\epsilon_i$ and $\delta_g$ are assumed to be independent.

Source: [official manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/lmer.pdf), Equation 2 and Table 2.